# wso2 IS: Oauth hidden by default; gives exceptions when manually "unhidden"

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

After installing the Identity Server, I can't follow the tutorial 
[here](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/securing-your-web-service-with-oauth2-using-wso2-identity-server-1/) 
because "OAuth" doesn't appear under main->manage in the admin console. Inspecting carbon.xml shows that it is hidden by default (reasonable explanations are welcome).

Enabling it in carbon.xml makes it appear, but when I register a new application, I get this error:

```
ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service() for servlet 
bridgeservlet threw exception {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher}
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.application.configure_002dservice_002dprovider_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.application.configure_002dservice_002dprovider_jsp:155)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
...

ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport} -  IO Error executing tag: JSPException
while including path '/application/configure-service-provider.jsp'. ServletException while 
including page. {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport}
java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/application/configure-service-provider.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:91)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
....
```

Anybody else seen this before? I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0

Comment: looks like 4.6.0 doesn't have these issues!

Answer (score 0):

That article was written for WSO2 IS 4.6.0 and have not tried in IS 5.0 yet. But you should be able to get it working with IS 5.0 too. The only challenge is IS 5.0 has a little different UI structure than 4.6.0.

For OAuth related configuration in IS 5.0, please go to `Service Providers` and add a new Service Provider. Then go to `Inbound Authentication Configurations` > `OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration` > `Configure`

Hope this helps.

Edit: You can find official docs [here](https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS500/Adding+a+Service+Provider).